# Назначение программы для батника

Tags: cmd, bat

Я хотел открыть батник в ворде, чтоб строки за экран не вылезали, "Открыть с помощью, Ворд. При этом галочка на "Открывать все файлы данного типа" была вообще неактивна. А теперь все батники открываются только в ворде, не исполняются. Подскажите, плиз, как мне это восстановить?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/53950

Comment: Я нашел вот что: https://i.postimg.cc/gkjYzCwW/image.jpg . Посмотрите, пожалуйста, какое значение b выставлено у вас. И в каком файле содержится реестр? Какой именно файл нужно скопировать перед редакцией реестра? Не regedt32.exe же.